# How to query SQL rows HAVING NOT (array values) in a field with comma separated values?

Tags: sql, arrays

I have a SQL table, which looks like this:

**id_question (int)** | **tags (varchar)**
where "tags" field is
- either empty : NULL
- or is filled with one value (Ex: 1) (not numeric)
- or is filled with several comma separated values (ex: 273,2308,24) (not numeric)

**id_question (int)** | **tags (varchar)**
1 | 1,373
2 | 283,4555,308,12
3 | 283,25,3

ANd i have a blacklisted_tags array.
I would like to retrieve id_questions of all questions whose tags field do not have a blacklisted  $tags_blacklist value.

**For example:**
$tags_blacklist = array (1,3)
=> I should get 2
and not 1 because it has 1 in its tags field
and not 3 because it has 3 in its tags field.

What should my SQL query look like?

Comment: first question: can you renormalize to a more proper structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your database design violates law of normalization #1: NEVER STORE COMMA-SEPARATED LISTS.

What you should have instead is this:

- id | tag
- 1 | 1
- 1 | 373
- 2 | 283
- 2 | 4555
- 2 | 308

etc.

This way your query becomes as easy as

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM YourTable
WHERE tag NOT IN (1, 3)
```

Comment: ...or more generically, "never store multi-valued fields".

Comment: Alright; I somewhat thought it would be easier for future use & search features to store my id_tags as comma separated values, but it seems I was wrong :)
Thank you all for the explanations and the reminders about best practices.

Comment: I have normalized my tables, now having a questions_tags table as you suggested me. Could you elaborate on the NOT IN (...) part ? How can I use my array in the SQL query ?

Comment: convert your array into a comma-separated string, and NOT IN(...) will do the trick

Comment: @Baptiste: I think you would be better off posting it as a new question. The answers would then be the attempts at solving your actual problem using the other design and wouldn't be mixed up with these ones. And this thread is good for educating other people, so I would just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

first suggestion, change your tables to the following:

```
question
---------
id

question_tag
------------
question_id
tag

blacklist
----------
tag
```